# How to define a static operator<<?

Tags: c++, static, operator-keyword, insertion

Is it possible to define a static insertion operator which operates on the static members of a class only? Something like:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static std::string msg;

    static MyClass& operator<< (const std::string& token) {
        msg.append(token);
        return *this;   // error, static
    }
};
```

alternatively:

```
static MyClass& operator<< (MyClass&, const std::string &token)
{
    MyClass::msg.append(token);
    return ?;
}
```

This is how I would like to use it:

```
MyClass << "message1" << "message2";
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ static operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390606/c-static-operator-overloading)

Comment: I'd say No, because `MyClass` isn't a value (it's a *type*), so `MyClass << "message"` is not a valid expression. You could just wrap `MyClass::msg` into a `std::istringstream`, though: `std::istringstream(MyClass::msg) << "hello" << "world";`

Comment: @KerrekSB you mean std::ostringstream , but I +1 your comment anyway

Comment: @wreckgar23: Ah, indeed I do - thanks!

Comment: @KerrekSB: If you meant `ostringstream`, I don't think it takes a string by reference.  IOW, in your snippet, `MyClass::msg` is left unmodified.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley it's true that it doesn't modify the original string, so would be best if MyClass::msg were an ostringstream

Comment: @wreckgar23: That would be the easy way, but perhaps not desirable if you don't want the user to have access to the full interface of `ostringstream`.  e.g. You may not want to give them the ability to clear the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the members of `MyClass` are static, it's possible to return a fresh instance.

However, returning a reference poses a problem. There are two solutions:

- define a static instance
- pass by copy, and not by reference.

The second approach is easiest:

```
static MyClass operator<< (MyClass, const std::string &token)
{
     MyClass::msg.append(token);
     return MyClass();
}
```

The first is one line more:

```
static MyClass& operator<< (MyClass&, const std::string &token)
{
     static MyClass instance;

     MyClass::msg.append(token);
     return instance;
}
```

Usage is very close to what you want:

```
MyClass() << "message1" << "message2";
```

---

However, **I would not recommend to do this**. Why don't you just just use a `std::ostringstream`? You'll get formatting and some more for free. If you really need global access, declare a global variable.

Answer (score 10):

What I would probably do in your situation, is create another class that overloads the `operator<<`, then make a static member of that type.  Like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static std::string msg;

    struct Out {
        Out & operator<< (const std::string& token) {
            MyClass::msg.append(token);
            return *this;
        }
    };

    static Out out;    
};
```

Using it is not *quite* what you asked for, but close enough I think:

```
MyClass::out << "message1" << "message2";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your class as cout, what you can do is example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace trace
{
  class trace
  {
  public:
    trace& operator<< (const std::string& echo)
    {
      std::cout << echo << std::endl;
      return *this;
    }
  };

  trace t; // Note that we created variable so we could use it.
};

using namespace trace; // Note that we use same namespace so we dont need to do trace::t
int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
  t << "Server started..."
    << "To exit press CTRL + Z";
  return 0;
}
```

Output should look like each string in new line like this:

Server started...
To exit press CTRL + Z

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A class-name / type is not a value in itself, you would need an expression like

```
class Foobar {...};

std::cout << Foobar << std::endl;
```

so that your static `operator<<` would be usable, but that is not valid C++. The grammar summary at A.4 shows that putting a type's name there is not valid.

Consider also that operator overloads are just functions with flaky names:

```
T  operator<< (T, T)
   ^^^^^^^^^^ flaky name, basically same as:
T  left_shift (T, T)
```

And functions in C++ (and most other languages, e.g. C#) can only work on instances of types, not types themselves.

However, C++ offers templates which have type arguments, howhowever, that would not help you to overload functions upon types.

Comment: Even if what is contained in the class **is** a value (_static_)?

Comment: @Pietro M: Yes. C++, put it to the point, has no notion of passing typenames as ordinary arguments to functions.